# Помогите разобраться с кодировками при передаче данных из ajax в сервлет

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlet

У меня есть форма, в которой будут только русские символы. В сервлет они приходят закодированные - в виде процентов с числами и буквами.
Так вот, как мне получить в сервлете человеческий текст?

так выглядит буква "ф"- %25D1%2584

пример кода на ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sendm").on("click",function(){
    var name=$("#names").val();
    var tema=$("#subject").val();
    var message=$("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/success",
        type: "POST",
        data :{"name":name,"tema":tema,"message":message},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(dat){
            if(dat.result=="success"){
            // window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/hello";
            }else{
                alert("fail");
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

В вашем случае кодирование символа произошло дважды (**!!**):

```
String f = "%25D1%2584";
String f_decoded = URLDecoder.decode(f, "UTF-8");
String f_decoded2 = URLDecoder.decode(f_decoded, "UTF-8");

System.out.println(f_decoded2);

// ф
```

Comment: а как можно это исправить на уровне ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Одной из причин неправильного кодирования является не кодирование tomcat в UTF-8

Вы должны добавить в свой tomcat в файл "server.xml" следующую строку:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

Заметка: это решение для Spring MVC